# change angular datatables filter's look

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

We are using angular datatable and in the backend webapi. We are using Light-column-filter http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withLightColumnFilter for serverside processing and it works perfectly as showed in the website. but we want to change the table filter's look to get more filter options (like contains, less than, greater than, equal) and its look like user friendly. it should be look like below image.

[we want these type of filter in the angular datatables with serverside processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4Gu.png)

image taken from www.ag-grid.com website but we want in angular-datatables with serverside processing. I spend a lot of time for this but didn't get any solution. please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? There is no simple answer to this, and any answer would require at least a low level dataTables plugin and major changes serverside.  In my opinion not suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have Done http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withLightColumnFilter. Its works fine at both side (frontend and backend wish serverside processing). I am looking for different FILTER looks as showed in http://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4Gu.png. I can manage serverside myself. I just want more filter option as like that image

Comment: @davidkonrad this is severside example http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withLightColumnFilter. but I want to change filter (TEXTBOX)